# Is there a way in python to not filter out escape sequence from a subprocess

Tags: python, windows, cmd, ansi-escape

here is the situation, I am wrapping a subprocess in windows that I am communicating with remotly.

```
connection_process = subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This is run with several threads polling for the stdout, stderr and writing to the stdin.
The remote side is running from linux and will be sending across all of it's data including ansi escape sequences.  For more information on these escape sequences http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_sequences.. 
The problem is two fold.
  I first need a way to translate these escape sequences to whatever windows uses before they are sent the the subprocess and vice versa.  Is there a good way of doing this in windows?  I have been looking at colorama, but is there a good example on how to do that?
  Second, I need to open my subprocess in a fashion that will give me everything in the full command prompt including the silly C:> at the beginning of each command line.  For some reason or another, python's popen won't give that to you.  It filters it out which is what people want, 99% of the time...  What is the way to tell popen to not filter it?
For reference here is my communicator code and an example of how it's being used.  After entering somthing, the C:> prompt is displayed. To reiterate my question, how do I get the subprocess to be exacly like a command window?

```
'''
Created on Mar 2, 2013

@author: rweber
'''
import subprocess
import Queue
from Queue import Empty
import threading


class Process_Communicator():

    def join(self):
        self.te.join()
        self.to.join()
        self.running = False
        self.aggregator.join()
        self.ti.join()

    def enqueue_in(self):
        while self.running and self.p.stdin is not None:
            while not self.stdin_queue.empty():
                s = self.stdin_queue.get()
                self.p.stdin.write(str(s) + '\n\r')
            pass

    def enqueue_output(self):
        if not self.p.stdout or self.p.stdout.closed:
            return
        out = self.p.stdout
        for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
            self.qo.put(line)

    def enqueue_err(self):
        if not self.p.stderr or self.p.stderr.closed:
            return
        err = self.p.stderr
        for line in iter(err.readline, b''):
            self.qe.put(line)

    def aggregate(self):
        while (self.running):
            self.update()
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        line = ""
        try:
            while self.qe.not_empty:
                line = self.qe.get_nowait()  # or q.get(timeout=.1)
                self.unbblocked_err += line
        except Empty:
            pass

        line = ""
        try:
            while self.qo.not_empty:
                line = self.qo.get_nowait()  # or q.get(timeout=.1)
                self.unbblocked_out += line
        except Empty:
            pass

        while not self.stdin_queue.empty():
                s = self.stdin_queue.get()
                self.p.stdin.write(str(s) + '\n\r')

    def get_stdout(self, clear=True):
        ret = self.unbblocked_out
        if clear:
            self.unbblocked_out = ""
        return ret

    def has_stdout(self):
        ret = self.get_stdout(False)
        if ret == '':
            return None
        else:
            return ret

    def get_stderr(self, clear=True):
        ret = self.unbblocked_out
        if clear:
            self.unbblocked_out = ""
        return ret

    def has_stderr(self):
        ret = self.get_stdout(False)
        if ret == '':
            return None
        else:
            return ret

    def __init__(self, subp):
        '''This is a simple class that collects and aggregates the
        output from a subprocess so that you can more reliably use
        the class without having to block for subprocess.communicate.'''
        self.p = subp
        self.unbblocked_out = ""
        self.unbblocked_err = ""
        self.running = True
        self.qo = Queue.Queue()
        self.to = threading.Thread(name="out_read",
                                    target=self.enqueue_output,
                                    args=())
        self.to.daemon = True  # thread dies with the program
        self.to.start()

        self.qe = Queue.Queue()
        self.te = threading.Thread(name="err_read",
                                   target=self.enqueue_err,
                                   args=())
        self.te.daemon = True  # thread dies with the program
        self.te.start()

        self.stdin_queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.aggregator = threading.Thread(name="aggregate",
                                           target=self.aggregate,
                                           args=())
        self.aggregator.daemon = True  # thread dies with the program
        self.aggregator.start()
        pass
def write_stdin(p,c):
    while p.poll() == None:
        i = raw_input("send to process:")
        if i is not None:
            c.stdin_queue.put(i)


p = subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
c = Process_Communicator(p)
stdin = threading.Thread(name="write_stdin",
                           target=write_stdin,
                           args=(p,c))
stdin.daemon = True  # thread dies with the program
stdin.start()
while p.poll() == None:
    if c.has_stdout():
        print c.get_stdout()
    if c.has_stderr():
        print c.get_stderr()

c.join()
print "Exit"
```

Better yet.. Here is the code for the ssh server that I have so far that I am working on..

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright (C) 2003-2007 Robey Pointer 
#
# This file is part of paramiko.
#
# Paramiko is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
# terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
# Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
# any later version.
#
# Paramiko is distrubuted in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY
# WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR
# A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Lesser General Public License for more
# details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
# along with Paramiko; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc.,
# 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307 USA.

import base64
from binascii import hexlify
import os
import socket
import sys
import threading
import traceback
import win32com
import win32net
import win32process
import win32security
import win32api
import paramiko
import ntsecuritycon
import Queue
import subprocess
try:
    import colorama
    colorama.init()
except:
    try:
        import tendo.ansiterm
    except:
        pass
#@todo max number of connections
#this is a map of user's and windows handles for
global user_handles 
user_handles = {}


def main():
# setup logging
    paramiko.util.log_to_file('demo_server.log')

    # @todo:  make the server so that it will automatically generate it's own keys
    '''
    if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd() , 'test_rsa.key')):
        from Crypto import Random
        random_generator = Random.new().read
        key = paramiko.rsakey.RSA.generate(2048, random_generator)
    '''
    #@todo: read key from a file first.. if file doesn't exist, make a new key and save it to the file.
    host_key = paramiko.RSAKey(filename='test_rsa', password="password")

    #host_key = paramiko.DSSKey(filename='test_dss.key')

    print 'Read key: ' + hexlify(host_key.get_fingerprint())
    run_server(host_key)




class Server (paramiko.ServerInterface):
    # 'data' is the output of base64.encodestring(str(key))
    # (using the "user_rsa_key" files)
    data = 'AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAIEAyO4it3fHlmGZWJaGrfeHOVY7RWO3P9M7hp' + \
           'fAu7jJ2d7eothvfeuoRFtJwhUmZDluRdFyhFY/hFAh76PJKGAusIqIQKlkJxMC' + \
           'KDqIexkgHAfID/6mqvmnSJf0b5W8v5h2pI/stOSwTQ+pxVhwJ9ctYDhRSlF0iT' + \
           'UWT10hcuO4Ks8='
    good_pub_key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=base64.decodestring(data))


    def __init__(self):
        self.event = threading.Event()
        '''self.AdjustPrivilege( ntsecuritycon.SE_CHANGE_NOTIFY_NAME )
        self.AdjustPrivilege( ntsecuritycon.SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME )
        self.AdjustPrivilege( ntsecuritycon.SE_TCB_NAME )
        ntsecuritycon.se

    def adjust_windows_privilages( self,  priv):
        flags =  ntsecuritycon.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | ntsecuritycon.TOKEN_QUERY
        htoken =  win32security.OpenProcessToken(win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), flags)
        id = win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(None, priv)
        newPrivileges = [(id, ntsecuritycon.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)]
        win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(htoken, 0, newPrivileges)'''

    def check_channel_request(self, kind, chanid):
        if kind == 'session':
            return paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED
        return paramiko.OPEN_FAILED_ADMINISTRATIVELY_PROHIBITED

    def check_auth_password(self, username, password):

        import re
        authorized = False
        try:    
            domain = win32api.GetDomainName()
            #@todo 
        except:
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()
        print domain
        if not authorized:
            try:
                hUser = win32security.LogonUser ( username,
                                                                    domain,
                                                                    password,
                                                                    win32security.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE ,
                                                                    win32security.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
                print hUser
            except win32security.error:
                print "Failed"
                import traceback
                traceback.print_exc()
                authorized = False
            except:
                import traceback
                traceback.print_exc()
                authorized = False
            else:
                print "Succeeded"
                authorized = True

        if not authorized:
            try:
                hUser = win32security.LogonUser ( username,
                                                                    domain,
                                                                    password,
                                                                    win32security.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE ,
                                                                    win32security.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
                print hUser
            except win32security.error:
                print "Failed"
                import traceback
                traceback.print_exc()
                authorized = False
            except:
                import traceback
                traceback.print_exc()
                authorized = False
            else:
                print "Succeeded"
                authorized = True

        if authorized and hUser is not None:
            user_handles[username] = hUser
            return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL
        else:   
            return paramiko.AUTH_FAILED

    def check_auth_publickey(self, username, key):
        print 'Auth attempt with key: ' + hexlify(key.get_fingerprint())
        #todo check the list of users to make sure that there is a user with that credential on the domian
        '''
        try:
            local_users =  win32net.NetGroupGetUsers( "localhost", 'none', 0)
            domain_controler = win32net.NetGetDCName()
            domain_user =  win32net.NetUseGetInfo(domain_controler, username, 1)
            users = []
            users.extend(local_users)
            users.append(domain_user)
        except:
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()
        for windows_user in users:
            windows_user_name = str(windows_user['name']).lower()
            print windows_user_name
            if  (windows_user_name == str(username).lower()) and (key == self.good_pub_key):
                print "Key was accepted"
                return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL
            else:
                print windows_user_name + " != " + str(username).lower()
        return paramiko.AUTH_FAILED'''
        if (key == self.good_pub_key):
            return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL
        else:
            return paramiko.AUTH_FAILED

    def get_allowed_auths(self, username):
        return 'password,publickey'

    def check_channel_shell_request(self, channel):
        self.event.set()
        return True

    def check_channel_pty_request(self, channel, term, width, height, pixelwidth,
                                  pixelheight, modes):
        return True

def run_server(host_key):
    # now connect
    while True:

        try:
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            #address = socket.get
            sock.bind(('', 22))

        except Exception, e:
            print '*** Bind failed: ' + str(e)
            traceback.print_exc()
            sys.exit(1)

        try:
            #@todo max number of connections
            sock.listen(100)
            print 'Listening for connection ...'
            # always be listening for connections
            connections = []
            while True:
                client, addr = sock.accept()
                #@todo add this to a thread that will handle each connection.
                new_connection = threading.Thread(name="connection_%s" % str(len(connections)),
                                           target=handle_connection,
                                           args=(client,addr,host_key))

                new_connection.setDaemon(True)  # thread dies with the program
                new_connection.start()
                connections.append(new_connection)
                print 'Got a connection!'
        except Exception, e:
            print '*** Listen/accept failed: ' + str(e)
            traceback.print_exc()
            sys.exit(1)

        print 'Got a connection!'

def handle_connection(client, addr, host_key):
    try:
        t = paramiko.Transport(client)
        try:
            t.load_server_moduli()
            username = t.get_username()
        except:
            print '(Failed to load moduli -- gex will be unsupported.)'
            raise
        t.add_server_key(host_key)
        server = Server()
        try:
            t.start_server(server=server)
        except paramiko.SSHException, x:
            print '*** SSH negotiation failed.'
            sys.exit(1)

        # wait for auth
        chan = t.accept()
        if chan is None:
            print '*** No channel.'
            sys.exit(1)
        print 'Authenticated!'
        #@todo: spawn a process and while the process is running communicate with it
        #open up a channel for stdin
        f = chan.makefile('rU')
        '''import pywintypes
        import win32pipe
        import pywintypes
        import win32process
        import win32con
        import win32api
        import win32file
        import string
        import types

        security_attributes = pywintypes.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES()
        security_attributes.bInheritHandle = 1
        Pyh_stdout_read_end, Pyh_stdout_write_end = win32pipe.CreatePipe(security_attributes, 0)
        Pyh_stderr_read_end, Pyh_stderr_write_end = win32pipe.CreatePipe(security_attributes, 0)
        Pyh_stdin_read_end, Pyh_stdin_write_end = win32pipe.CreatePipe(security_attributes, 0)'''

        connection_process = subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        '''creationFlags = win32process.CREATE_NO_WINDOW
        startupInfo = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
        startupInfo.dwFlags = win32process.STARTF_USESTDHANDLES
        startupInfo.hStdInput = Pyh_stdout_read_end
        startupInfo.hStdOutput = Pyh_stdout_write_end
        startupInfo.hStdError = Pyh_stderr_write_end'''
        #PyHANDLE, PyHANDLE, int, int = CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, appName ,
        #commandLine , processAttributes , threadAttributes , bInheritHandles , dwCreationFlags , newEnvironment , currentDirectory , startupinfo )
        #@todo: use the correct user's handle in creating the process so that it spawns as that user.           
        #hProcess, hThread, dwProcessId, dwThreadId = win32process.CreateProcessAsUser(user_handles[username], None, r"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", None, None, 1, 0, None, 
        #hProcess, hThread, dwProcessId, dwThreadId = win32process.CreateProcess(None, r"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", None, None, 1, 0, None,
        #                                      None, startupInfo)
        #stdout = open(Pyh_stdout_read_end)
        #temp = stdout.readline()
        #print temp
        communicator = Process_Communicator(connection_process)
        #communicator = win32_Process_Communicator(Pyh_stdout_read_end,Pyh_stderr_read_end, Pyh_stdin_write_end)
        communicator.stdin_queue.put("\r")
        #username = f.readline().strip('\r\n')
        while not connection_process.poll():
            server.event.wait(10)
            if not server.event.isSet():
                print '*** Client never asked for a shell.'
                sys.exit(1)

            if communicator.has_stdout() and chan.send_ready():
                chan.send(communicator.get_stdout())
            if communicator.has_stderr() and chan.send_ready():
                #chan.send_stderr(communicator.get_stderr())
                chan.send(communicator.get_stderr())
            stdin_string = ''
            while f.channel.recv_ready():
                stdin_string += f.read(1)
                #str = f.readline()
                translator = colorama.ansitowin32.AnsiToWin32()
                translator.write_and_convert(stdin_string)
                communicator.stdin_queue.put(stdin_string)

        chan.close()

    except Exception, e:
        print '*** Caught exception: ' + str(e.__class__) + ': ' + str(e)
        traceback.print_exc()
        try:
            t.close()
        except:
            pass
        sys.exit(1)

class Process_Communicator():

    def join(self):
        self.te.join()
        self.to.join()
        self.running = False
        self.aggregator.join()
        self.ti.join()

    def enqueue_in(self):
        while self.running and self.p.stdin is not None:
            while not self.stdin_queue.empty():
                s = self.stdin_queue.get()
                self.p.stdin.write(str(s) + '\n\r')
            pass

    def enqueue_output(self):
        if not self.p.stdout or self.p.stdout.closed:
            return
        out = self.p.stdout
        for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
            self.qo.put(line)

    def enqueue_err(self):
        if not self.p.stderr or self.p.stderr.closed:
            return
        err = self.p.stderr
        for line in iter(err.readline, b''):
            self.qe.put(line)

    def aggregate(self):
        while (self.running):
            self.update()
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        line = ""
        try:
            while self.qe.not_empty:
                line = self.qe.get_nowait()  # or q.get(timeout=.1)
                self.unbblocked_err += line
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass

        line = ""
        try:
            while self.qo.not_empty:
                line = self.qo.get_nowait()  # or q.get(timeout=.1)
                self.unbblocked_out += line
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass

        while not self.stdin_queue.empty():
                s = self.stdin_queue.get()
                self.p.stdin.write(str(s))

    def get_stdout(self, clear=True):
        ret = self.unbblocked_out
        if clear:
            self.unbblocked_out = ""
        return ret

    def has_stdout(self):
        ret = self.get_stdout(False)
        if ret == '':
            return None
        else:
            return ret

    def get_stderr(self, clear=True):
        ret = self.unbblocked_out
        if clear:
            self.unbblocked_out = ""
        return ret

    def has_stderr(self):
        ret = self.get_stdout(False)
        if ret == '':
            return None
        else:
            return ret

    def __init__(self, subp):
        '''This is a simple class that collects and aggregates the
        output from a subprocess so that you can more reliably use
        the class without having to block for subprocess.communicate.'''
        self.p = subp
        self.unbblocked_out = ""
        self.unbblocked_err = ""
        self.running = True
        self.qo = Queue.Queue()
        self.to = threading.Thread(name="out_read",
                                    target=self.enqueue_output,
                                    args=())
        self.to.daemon = True  # thread dies with the program
        self.to.start()

        self.qe = Queue.Queue()
        self.te = threading.Thread(name="err_read",
                                   target=self.enqueue_err,
                                   args=())
        self.te.daemon = True  # thread dies with the program
        self.te.start()

        self.stdin_queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.aggregator = threading.Thread(name="aggregate",
                                           target=self.aggregate,
                                           args=())
        self.aggregator.daemon = True  # thread dies with the program
        self.aggregator.start()
        pass

class win32_Process_Communicator():
    def __init__(self,read_end_of_stdout, read_end_of_stderr, write_end_of_stdin):
        pass
main()
```

Comment: So you're trying to run commands on a remote Windows machine and get the output back to the calling process on a Linux machine?

Comment: yes.  Making a totally pythonic paramiko based ssh server, hopefully be able to open source it if I can work out the finer details.

Comment: The indentation of your code is messed-up.

Comment: Hmm.. repasted it.  Try it now.